# how to create multiple Fileupload controls dynamically based on database values

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, multifile-uploader

i would like to create multiple FileUpload controls dynamically based on my database values

here i am posting some code

```
 <div id="FileUpload123" runat="server" align=center style="width:250px; line-height:26px;">

</div>
```

i getting some count value from database and storing that value into a integer variable.

based on that count value i used one for loop to create fileupload controls

```
for (int j = 1; j <= page_count; j++)
       {
           FileUpload fop = new FileUpload();
           fop.ID = today.Text + "_Page_" + j.ToString();
           fop.Style.Add("margin-bottom", "10px");
           FileUpload123.Controls.Add(fop);

       }
```

upto this it is working fine but while uploading files into database

i am getting "object reference not set to an instance of a object error"

here is the code here

```
string str = Server.MapPath("main_pages");
        for (int j = 1; j <= page_count; j++)
        {
            string st = today.Text + "_Page_" + j.ToString();
            FileUpload fop = (FileUpload)FileUpload123.FindControl(st);
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(fop.PostedFile.FileName);
            fop.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("main_pages/" + st + ".jpg"));
            if (fop.HasFile)
            {
                fop.SaveAs(str + "\\" + st + ".jpg");
            }
        }
```

even if i select a file in fileupload it is showing null

please help me ... thanks in advance....

Comment: Create GridView add FileUpload Control inside Template Field

Comment: which event are you creating the fileupload controls in? page_load pr page_init